# Android list view shows images randomly

Tags: android, android-listview, thumbnails

I have a file selector (which works as needed) but I wanted to add thumbnails to the list when appropriate.  It works well enough for the first few images but then random file (and folder) items which are not images and should not have thumbnails take on random images that have already loaded.  The whole list of of files eventually takes an image after repeated scrolling.

Is this a known issue with list views?  Is there a standard way of showing thumbnails?  Is my code just broken?

Below is the code the assigns the filenames and thumbnails to each list item - the class extends the `ArrayAdapter`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }
    final Option o = items.get(position);
    if (o != null)
    {
        TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        try
        {
            if(o.getData()!="Folder" && (o.getPath().contains(".jpg") || o.getPath().contains(".gif") || o.getPath().contains(".png")))
                img1.setImageBitmap(getPreview(o.getPath()));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("Image failed in File Viewer", e);
        }
        if (t1 != null)
            t1.setText(o.getName());
        if (t2 != null)
            t2.setText(o.getData());

    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing your views (which is the correct way). So when you start scrolling it will reuse the views that were displayed before. So all you have to do is reset the image/texts in your views when you're not setting them.